# How to identifie UUID of ble from bluetooth service specifications?

Tags: service, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently i am working on heart rate monitor and i found that "2A37" is uuid which is used for getting heart rates data from hrm device. Then i searched a lot but i don't find, why i should use "2A37" and not other for getting heart rates data.

I have gone through the information of below link of bluetooth site but still i am confused.

https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx.

Can anyone please make me understand how can i decide different uuids for diffrent services.

Example:
Suppose i need to get battery data from hrm device then, from Bluetooth services information how can i find UUID of battery services data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

0x2A37 is the UUID for the [Heart Rate Measurement](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) characteristic.  You use that number because the spec says that is what it is.  The heart rate service is 0x180D.  The page you linked to has the numbers in the table.  Battery service is 0x180F.  What you will need to read is the [battery level characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml) which is 0x2A19.  You just have to click the battery service and then click the battery characteristic to find the relevant page with all the details.

Comment: Getting "403 Forbidden"  error on click to your both links, Please update these.

Comment: Saddly teh BT website has killed off all the nice online stuff.  You need to go and download the apriopriate spec document from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/